# Data-table column width issue mozilla

Tags: html, css, tabs, datatables

I am using data-table for one of my project. I that case, after ajax request(which return the view) I am initializing data table on response data, with sorting option. The table contains large number of columns and have  horizontal scroll bar, which is fine for me.

The problem is column header are not rendering properly, they are coming on new line, as shown.

[image: Header columns are coming on new line]

This is my initialization code:

```
    //There can be multiple instances of datatable created after ajax request.
    $('.query_result_table').each(function(){

                    var temp = $(this).dataTable( {
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bDestroy":true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    /*"bAutoWidth": true,
                    "sScrollXInner": "100%",*/
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "bSortable": false, 
                        "aTargets": [ 'no_click' ]
                    }],
                    "fnInitComplete": function() {
                        this.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    }
                });

                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    temp.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                }, 10);
                 //$(this).fnAdjustColumnSizing();

  });
```

The above problem seems to be in Mozilla. In Chrome, it is working fine.

Any idea how can I resolve this.

-- Many thanks for your time

Comment: It could be a problem with css. Have you checked it?

Comment: I haven't given width to cell via css, I have cross checked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had resolved the issue as follows:

```
   //There can be multiple instances of datatable created after ajax request.
    $('.query_result_table').each(function(){

                    var temp = $(this).dataTable( {
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bDestroy":true,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,  //Disabled auto width calculation....
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {
                        "bSortable": false, 
                        "aTargets": [ 'no_click' ]
                    }],
                    "fnInitComplete": function() {
                        this.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    }
                });

                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    temp.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                }, 10);
                 //$(this).fnAdjustColumnSizing();

  });
```

**CSS:**

```
.query_result_table {
    width:2500px;
    max-width:none;  
}
```